# Unable to print 5 integers in one line

Tags: c

I have written below code. I wanted to print the numbers from **0 to 49**, but excluding the numbers divisible by 7. Also only 5 numbers will be printed in one line. When I execute the project, the result I get is

```
1     2      3
4     5      6      8     9
10    11     12     13    15
16     17    18     19    20
22     23    24     25    26
and so on
```

My question is why the new line is getting added after number `3`? Why there are only 3 elements in first row? I am using codeblock + mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
 void main()
{
        /*Program to declare 50 elements integer arrary; fill the array with number*/

        int myarray[50];
        int count;
        int count1;

        for(count=0;count<50;count++)
        {
            myarray[count]=count;
            //printf("%d\t",count);
        }

        for(count=0;count<50;count++)
        {
            if((count%7)==0)
            {
                continue;   // Do not print numbers divisible by 7
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d\t",myarray[count]);
                count1++;
                // Print only 5 numbers per line
                if((count1%5)==0)
                   {
                       printf("\n");
                   }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: `count1` is not initialized. It can have any value, and may be dividable by 5 at any moment.

Comment: Oh my god. Got it and thanks for noticing this. But why I do not get warning in such case? I had enabled all common compiler warnings. Any other settings in codeblock?

Comment: Hmmm...should have posted the simple comment as an answer. My reputation points are growing only slowly... Jon, I don't know Codeblocks. Some other compilers do give warnings. You could have used a debugger and would have seen `count1` had a funny value.

Comment: amongst other problems, the returned type from `main()` is always `int`, so the main() signature should be:  `int main( void )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialise `count1`, this code should work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    /*Program to declare 50 elements integer arrary; fill the array with number*/

    int myarray[50];
    int count;
    int count1=0; //initialisation

    for(count=0;count<50;count++)
    {
        myarray[count]=count;
        //printf("%d\t",count);
    }

    for(count=0;count<50;count++)
    {
        if((count%7)==0)
        {
            continue;   // Do not print numbers divisible by 7
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\t",myarray[count]);
            count1++;

            if((count1/5)==0) // if the counter is 5 print a "\n"
               {
                   printf("\n");
                   count1=0;  // put count1 equal 0 
               }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `count1`, it is not initialized so the program should be starting with some trash in the memory allocated to the variable. This is why your code is having this odd behavior.

Answer (score 1):

initialize count1 as 0.
you can get new line after 5 numbers.
Because if you don't initialize count1 may have any value.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `count1` is not initialized.

Also you could shorten your code to 1 loop.

An easier way of doing this would be:

```
    int myarray[50];
    int number = 0; // number from 0 to 49
    int index = 0; // index of the array, only increments when a valid number is found

    for(number;number<50;number++) // iterate from 0 to 49
    {
        if(number % 7 != 0){ // if number is not divisible by 7
           myarray[index]=number; // add the number to the array
           printf("%d ", number); // print the number
           if(index % 5 == 0){ // if 5 numbers have been added, print a \n
              printf("\n");
           }
           index++; // increment index
        } 
    }
```